# C# sqlDataReader.Read() causing Convertion failed error

Tags: c#, sql, type-conversion, sqldatareader

The query for the database is working fine and returning the rows. 
But at some point, about 2 minutes into running the program, it crashes with the error below.

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion
>   failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows) 
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean
>   setTimeout, Boolean& more)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()    at
>   TrackChanges.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\ari.downey\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\TrackChanges\TrackChanges\Program.cs:line 31 Press any
>   key to continue . . .

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (read.Read())
    {
        if (read[4].ToString().ToUpper() != columns[4].ToUpper())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < read.FieldCount; i++)
                Console.Write(read[i] + " || " + columns[i] + " ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }
    }                       
    conn.Close();
}
```

I apologize that the code is plain text. I need to ask a question to get more reputation but I have no relevant questions other than this to ask.

Comment: If you can edit, edit the question and add the SQL executed, if you cannot, add it as a comment so it can be added to the question

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: **Conversion
failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int.**. You have to check for `null`

Comment: When querying an SQL database you should use parameters in the query.  Otherwise, the drive try to guess datatypes and sometimes guesses wrong.  It is like using GENERAL cell type in excel workbook.

Comment: Its just  select * from table where id = "";

Comment: @jdweng, I have a select statement which selects rows by its Id. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko , Where should I be checking for null? As the error is pointing to the .Read() and that returns a bool if there is another row.

Comment: Is Id in database defined as an integer or varchar?  You could be getting a null if there is a mismatch between query and database.  If id is an integer then use : id = 123.  If id is varchar then use id = '123'.  The single quote in the sql server will convert an integer to a string which may result in no data returned.

Comment: Double check the SQL. Error might not be from the DataReader! 
I encountered this error but ultimately found that while surfaced by the Data Reader the issue was in the underlying stored procedure (SProc) - and EXACTLY as the error message indicated. We had some UNIONs and all but one of them treated a given col/value as INT. However, a recently added UNION (select) treated the column as VARHCAR(NN). Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your count starts at 1 when the array data starts at 0?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here might be that the conversion being done is not possible. INT can never be **NULL**, it has to be **0**. You can also not convert the varchar/string value of 'NULL' to int, because that does not represent a integer value.

As described in the exception you got.
*Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int.*

Try using **Int32.TryParse**. You should be able to catch and handle the **NULL** value.